# Gunicorn workers timeout after making requests to Flask app

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have a small flask app that I have dockerized running Gunicorn as a WSGI and it seems Flask is possibly not completing the requests fully as the workers are timing out. You can see the behavior in the logs bellow.

Here is my Gunicorn start command from my Dockerfile for the app as well:

```
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "-b", ":8080", "app:app", "--log-level=debug", "--workers=9", "-t 30"]
```

```
[2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [15] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:46 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] 9 workers
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:55 +0000] [14] [DEBUG] GET /users
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:19:55 +0000] [9] [DEBUG] GET /favicon.ico
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:20:25 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14)
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:20:25 +0000] [14] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14)
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:20:26 +0000] [26] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:21:26 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:9)
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:21:26 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:15)
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:21:26 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:21:26 +0000] [15] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 15)
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:21:26 +0000] [28] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 28
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:21:26 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] 8 workers
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:21:26 +0000] [29] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29
wsgi_1  | [2020-03-03 23:21:26 +0000] [1] [DEBUG] 9 workers
```

Any idea on what might be causing these requests to timeout in this manner? The timeouts do not seem to be causing any specific issues with the app but I imagine this could be an issue in production. It appears not to be related to any specific route of my app. As you can see even loading a favicon can trigger the issue. The issue does not appear to be specific to my app as running the standard [Flask Hello World](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) also results in the same behavior.

Comment: What's your Operating System?

Comment: @SaiprasadBalasubramanian The base image for the container is Ubuntu 18.10.